# pass two arguments in python property setter

Tags: python, class

```
class MyClass(object):
   def __init__(self, name):
     self.name = name
     self._prof = None
     self._ischanged = False

   @property 
   def prof(self):
     if not self._prof:
        self._prof = "Sample Prof"
     return self._prof

   @prof.setter
   def prof(self, value, anothervalue):
      pass
```

Here you can get the prof using:

```
myclass = MyClass("sam")

myclass.prof
```

but I can't find a way to set the values of prof.

In the above code, how would I pass two values to prof?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't pass two values to a setter.  when you do:

```
instance.property = whatever
```

python calls the setter with `instance` (as `self`) and `whatever` as arguments.

---

You *can* pass a 2-tuple though:

```
myclass.prof = ('one', 'two')
```

In this case, the setter will get passed the 2-tuple `('one', 'two')` as the value.  If that isn't what you want, you're better off using a vanilla method to set the values.  e.g.:

```
myclass.set_prof(value1, value2)
```

Comment: Pedantically `myclass.prof = 'one', 'two'`  - parentheses are superfluous.

Comment: @cdarke -- Yep.  I would normally leave them off, but in this case, I wanted to make it more clear that the tuple is a single entity that will get passed to the setter so I left them on.

Comment: I would go with vanilla method. Sometimes it is overkill to be too pythonic.

Comment: @paris_serviola -- I would argue that the vanilla method _is_ the pythonic way to do this, however without knowing your actual use-case, it's a bit tricky to say for sure.